# SQL fetch in tables

Tags: html, mysql

First of all. I apologize for the poor English. I'm also sorry for the novice level of this question.

I would like to put my SQL results in a table, and add a new row for every result.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
  while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
    echo "<p><b>".$results['FNAME']."</b> " .$results['LNAME']." ".$results['AGE']."</p>";
  }
}
```

So I would like `[FNAME] in a own TD`, `[LNAME] in it's on TD` and the same with [AGE].

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just put `<tr>` around each row of data, `<td>` around each column, and put everything inside `<table>`.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>LAst Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>";
    while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw_results) {
        echo "<tr><td>{$results['FNAME']}</td><td>{$results['LNAME']}</td><td>{$results['AGE']}</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
  if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
     echo "<tr><td>" . $results['FNAME'] . "</td><td>" . $results['LNAME'] . "</td><td>" .$results['AGE']."</td></tr>";
    }
  }
?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```